# Deduce if parameters passed to one funcion are equal to parameters in an operator

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns

I have this class :

```
class A
{
public:
    //copy and move constructor,operator=

    A func(const A& a,const A& b)
    {
        A c;
        //do some stuff...        
        return c;
    }

};
```

It works fine when I use it in this way :

```
A a;
A b;
A c=func(a,b);
```

But the problem is when I use it in this way :

```
A a;
A b;
a=func(a,b);
```

It does some unnecessary stuff (making c and in my class calling constructor is time consuming!)

I want to know if a is equal to one of variables that pass to function then I don't make c and do stuff in-place

After thinking for a while I came up with this solution :

```
class A
{
public:
    //copy and move constructor and operator=

    A func(const A& a,const A& b)
    {
        A c;
        //do some stuff...        
        return c;
    }
    A func(const A& a,const A& b,bool inPlace)
    {
        if(!inPlace)
            return func(a,b);
        else
        {
            //const-cast a then do stuff on a 
            return a;
        }
    }

};
```

now It works fine with :

```
A a;
A b;
A c=func(a,b);
a=func(a,b,true);
```

But still it doesn't work with :

```
A a;
A b;
b=func(a,b,true);
```

So another overload for `func` is needed .

But It seems a bad design . Any better idea for making this class ?

Note that I don't want to make func like this :

```
void func(const A& a,const A& b,A& result)
```

(And sorry about the question title I cant find a better one :) )

**EDIT**

My constructor looks like this :

```
A(unsigned int SIZE)
{
    // all of these are vectors and SIZE is about 1k
    realData_.reserve(SIZE);
    timePerUnit_.reserve(SIZE);
    prob_.reserve(SIZE);
    //.... 

    // some math stuff for filling them

}
```

Comment: can you please add constructor of `class A`

Comment: In the class A use operator overloading for = operator. This enables you to assign the returned object correctly.

Comment: Did you define the move assignment operator?

Comment: declare copy constructor and assignment operator for your class and then try find how the flow is.... I am sure you will find the answers then...

Comment: @vathsa yes I define it but It doesn't prevent calling c constructor in a=func(a,b);

Comment: when function returns, the return values are stored in temporary object which gets assigned to `a`... if you are returning object ,copy constructor will be called not matter what...

Comment: @Hades copy constructor is not the problem because I defined move constructor . the problem is with making this object when It is not necessary ... I mean A c; (see the first code)

Comment: Why does `b=func(a,b,true)` not work? What does it do that is other than what you expect? Also: please don't declare `const A& a` and then const_cast to modify a. If you need to modify a, then declare it as `A& a`.

Comment: @WernerHenze because size of vectors in b are different from a .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From how I understand your question you want to write a `A &func(const A& a,const A& b)` which returns a newly constructed A. But as an optimization you want to modify a or b and not construct a new A if the result of func is assigned to a or b.

When you are writing `a = func(a, b)` this is like `a.operator=(func(a, b))`. func will not know how its return value is used and operator= will not know that its parameter is coming from func. If you want to optimize for that special case you need to write extra functions for it.

You could write an unoptimized and an optimized version:

```
A &func(const A& a, const A& b) { A c; ...; return c; }
void func(A& a, const A& b) { modify a; }
void func(const A& a, A& b) { modify b;}
// In case func(a,b)==func(b,a) for const a and const b you can write:
void func(const A& a, A& b) { func(b, a); }
```

Or you could write a generic version:

```
void func(const A& a, const A& b, A& result)
{
    if(&result == &a)
        optimized modify result;
    else if(&result == &b)
        optimized modify result;
    else
        unoptimized modify result;
}
```

In case you are lucky you do not even need to distinguish between the different cases in the generic version. But this depends on the calculations you are doing.

BTW, if you are looking at the STL you will see that they are doing something similar. Replace A with string and func with `operator+` and you will end up with `string operator+ (const string& lhs, const string& rhs);`. This operator will always create a new object which it returns. To optimize for the case `str1 = str1 + str2;` the STL declares an extra function `operator+=`. That's the same thing that you will need to do - only that your functions have the name func and not operator ... .

Answer (score 1):

If you definitely don't want to use:

```
void func(const A& a, const A& b, A& result)
```

Then you can get away with a single overload by using a pointer for your third argument instead of a bool, like:

```
A func(const A& a, const A& b, const A* resultPlace = NULL)
{
    if (resultPlace == &a) {
       // Do in place stuff with a
       return a;
    }
    else if (resultPlace == &b) {
       // Do in place stuff with b
       return b;
    }
    else {
        A c;
        // whatever
        return c;
    }
}
```

Of course, you would call this like:  `b = func(a, b, &b);`

Not sure if you can do any better than this, but I doubt you'll be able to do what your question title asks specifically.